# How can I give full admin access to my current account on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, administrator

The type of privileges I am looking for are the ones that the administrator account has access to (when typing net user in a command prompt, there is an account literally named "administrator".) Those privileges include having everything constantly running as administrator and never having the admin prompt pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The "Administrator" user is disabled by default and should remain disabled. That is a good design point by Microsoft.

Your user (assuming it was the first user of the computer) is a member of the Administrator's group. Make it a member if not.

All Administrators must OK numerous activities that require Admin authority. That is a function of User Account Control. This also should be left ON. Indeed, I think it needs to be ON to use the Microsoft Store. That used to be the case in any event.

The first Windows 10 user (member of Administrators) can do anything at all in the operating system that can be done.

A few technical apps require a UAC OK to run, and that is helpful and legitimate to let you know you are running this type of App.

Comment: Is there a way to always run everything as admin, even on startup other than modifying the properties of each app individually?

Comment: It depends on the app. Most apps run just fine (Office, Adobe, Browsers, File Explorer, VMware and so on). A few technical apps (Comm View packet sniffer) need to be OK'd and that works fine for me. If a Service, you can set it up in Task Scheduler to run with highest authority (some Anti Virus updates are like this). Some apps (Sync Back) have Manifest files you can set to run without UAC interaction. So it highly depends on the application.

Comment: What I meant is that when you right click on a program and click on properties, you have an option to set it to always run as admin. Is there a way to do that for every single program without having to right click on every single one of them individually?

Comment: Not every single program. There are thousands of Windows programs and they work the way the application designer wrote them. It seems to me that you would not have an excessive number of these. I do not, and I run many applications.